# Where can I download the Javadocs for the Eclipse plugin developement SDK

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javadoc

I am working on an Eclipse plugin development. Where can I download the Javadocs for the Eclipse plugin development API? I am able to refer them online [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Foverview-summary.html), but I want to download them for offline reference and associate them to the plugin jars. It is even better if I can somehow associate the source code to the plugin jars as well. I am using Juno. Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks!

Update:
I tried installing Eclipse RCP and then installed the plugin packages from Eclipse Java EE on to it. Thereby I could see the sources and Javadoc. I am not sure if this is the only / best way to include the RCP Javadoc and source, but it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the Eclipse SDK. I assume that you are running on Juno.  Two possibilities:

1. Start from scratch and download the Eclipse Classic distribution from the downloads page
2. Add this update site to your installer: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2 and install the Eclipse SDK.